# Stop MS Edge from injecting its tabs into Alt-Tab switcher

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

After an upgrade to Windows 10 20H2, the **MS Edge** browser started hogging the Alt-Tab switcher and injecting its tabs into it.

It seems right now it injects up to 5 tabs.

This is very annoying, as switching away from MS Edge takes anywhere between 1 to 5 presses of Alt-Tab (depending on how many tabs are open).

Hence the question: how to make it stop doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://betanews.com/2020/08/18/remove-edge-tabs-from-alt-tab-switcher/):

- **Start** -> **Settings** -> **System** -> **Multitasking** -> **Alt + Tab**
- Change "**Open windows and 5 most recent tabs in Edge**" to "**Open windows only**"

  [image: edge alt-tab disable]